# After implementing 'extends Service' in Android, how do I fix these errors?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I am currently working on a code that I need to convert from 'extends Activity' to 'extends Service'. I need this because I need to have my app running (the audio being played) in the background even if the phone is in sleep mode. However, doing so caused me some errors. I have no idea how to fix this. As recommended by eclipse, I removed '@Override' before 'protected void onCreate...'. But it still has some errors with functions under it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_p_3);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
        p_e=0;
        second_display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        minute_display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        hour_display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

The ones I am having problems with are:

```
requestWindowFeature
onCreate
setContentView
setRequestedOrientation
findViewById

finish(); (from another child class)
```

Are there equivalent codes in Activity that I can use in Service?

How do I fix these? I really need help.

Comment: Just replacing `Activity` by `Service` won't make it a Service.

Comment: `Are there equivalent codes in Activity that I can use in Service?` No ... `How do I fix these?` you have to learn [Android Fundementals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, no, there isn't - apart from `onCreate` which has different argument set in Service than it does in an Activity.  What you need to understand is that a Service runs in the background and does not contain any UI of its own.  Hence, window features, views, orientation don't apply for a service.

I suggest you start by reading the Service documentation on google.  Pay attention to the service lifecycle.

Assuming you want a simple app that plays sounds - and continues to do so even when the phone goes to sleep or your activity is removed from the foreground - then what you need is a combination of an Activity and a Service.  Activity would contain all the user interface - exactly as it does now for you.  What would change is the sound playback.  Instead of playing sound from an activity, you would do so from a service.  You will then need to have a communication going between your service and the activity - to update the UI (from service to activity) and to control playback (from activity to service).

[Section on Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in Android developer guide provides good information on how to achieve this - and more.

Comment: I read some parts of the documentation. It helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These methods don't exist in a `Service`. The reason is, that you *don't need them*.
All these methods are only available for Activities, because they are needed for displaying data/views.

A Service cannot display anything. Check the [Android fundamentals page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Comment: Should I use abstraction?

Comment: @ChristopherTreanor what does abstraction has to do with it? You're using the **wrong component** to archive your goals.